# Vistual Studio 2008 SP1 debugging not working with IIS process (sometimes)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, debugging, iis-7

I am using VS 2008 SP1 on Windows 7 and tyring to debug a ASP.net website project by attaching debugger to w3wp process, I noticed that debugger wont stop at the breakpoint at everytime. I researched a lot on this issue and found that its a known issue see this link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957912. I tried hotfix but still I am facing the same issue, its really annoying to test. Anyone had this issue?

Note: I am using Asp.net routing feature which introduced in .net 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run Visual Studio as an administrator otherwise you are not allowed to attach the debugger to another process.

Or do you sometimes compile in release mode? You also have to set the option debug='true' in the configuration file (it depends on where you set the breakpoint) and set the correct mode when attaching the debugger (attach to managed code).

The breakpoint is also not hit, when you not run the latest version of the code. Make sure you rebuild the code before you attach to w3wp.exe. Start the code with F5 in debug mode should always work.

Comment: I do run Visual studio as administrator, the issue is- debugger is not stopping at the break point every time, its random. Sometimes it stops and sometimes it just does not stop.

Comment: you never compile in release mode?

Comment: I set debug="true" in my config file and also debugger is attached to managed code. I never compile it in release mode. I set up everything in VS studio, browse my webisite. I have break point on my NetPage OnLoad method, (public class NetPage : System.Web.UI.Page) but on some pages it never hits to breakpoint, its totally random.

Comment: @Akshay: do you mean it hits the same breakpoint at random or do you have different breakpoints? Are you sure the code is excecuted? You could add a Trace.Write() call and have a look in the trace whether your code runs or not.

Comment: yes, it stops at the same breakpoint but sometimes it never hits it, I am sure that my code runs all of the time because otherwise page wont get rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you select "Managed code" in "attach to" dialog. 
And, just in case, maybe it's a problem with your routing and there is nothing to do with debugger?